# Cart not displaying after one click on icon

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning JavaScript so I tried to practice it while learning.
still, I don't code the cart button but yes I coded the cart icon showing on the right top by default the cart display is none. When the user clicks on the cart icon the cart display = block but after clicking one time the cart icon is not opening the cart or not displaying the cart. The close button is working well.

See the image and code it's really simple.

[image]

```
<nav>
  <span id="cart-icon"><i class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></i></span>
</nav>
<div class="main">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="img.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5>Photo</h5>
      <p>Price: $5</p>
      <button>Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cart" id="cart">
  <span id="close"><i class="fas fa-close"></i></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `scale(1)` instead of `block`;

```js
cart.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
```

```js
const cart = document.querySelector(".cart");
const icon = document.querySelector(".icon");
const cross = document.querySelector(".close");

cross.addEventListener("click", () => {
  cart.style.transform = "scale(0)";
});

icon.addEventListener("click", () => {
  cart.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
});
```

```css
html {
  font: 300 4vmin/1.2 "Segoe UI"
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  height: 10vh;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 2px groove grey;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 98vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: max-content;
  min-width: 22rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

legend {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.cart {
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.cart legend {
  margin-left: auto;
  background: transparent
}

figure {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  padding: 0;
}

figcaption {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
}

button {
  float: right;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fas {
  line-height: 1rem;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fas:hover {
  color: magenta;
  transition: 0.3s
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav>
  <menu>
    <a href="#" class="fas fa-shopping-basket icon"></a>
  </menu>
</nav>
<main>
  <section class="card">
    <fieldset class="card-body">
      <legend>Photo</legend>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://placem.at/things?w=240&h=135&random=1&txt=$5&txtclr=fc0
" alt="" />
        <figcaption>Price: $5</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <button>Add to Cart</button>
    </fieldset>
  </section>
  <fieldset class="cart">
    <legend>
      <a href="#" class="fas fa-close close"></a>
    </legend>
  </fieldset>
</main>
```